# Why does the order in which fragments are added via the SupportFragmentManger matter?

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments, facebook-android-sdk

I am in the process of creating an `AuthenticationActivity` which will provide users the option of logging in via Facebook, Twitter or app specific auth. After following the well written [tutorial *Use Facebook Login* from the Facebook Android SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/) I had Facebook authentication working.

Unfortunately, when I proceeded to add a Twitter Fragment to provide similar login functionality I ran into issues. Suddenly the Facebook login button would not change state and my authentication to Facebook would not fully complete, though I could see authentication callbacks being returned.

After going round and round I finally decided to change the order that the `AuthenticationActivity` adds fragments via the `SupportFragmentManager`. When I did Facebook started working again, but then Twitter fragment broke.

```java
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(android.R.id.content, twitterFragment)
    .add(android.R.id.content, facebookFragment)
    .commit();
```

Rather than make me feel better this made me feel worse. I admit to not fully understanding fragments, but am totally puzzled as to why the order in which the fragments are added has this affect. Which ever comes first does not work, but the one added second does. It may be important to note that I am utilizing [actionbarsherlock](/questions/tagged/actionbarsherlock) and its fragment implementation.

Below you will find my activity and fragment code

**AuthenticationActivity**

```java
public class AuthenticationActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private FacebookFragment facebookFragment;
    private TwitterFragment twitterFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            addFragments();
        } else {
            restoreFragments();
        }
    }

    private void addFragments() {
        facebookFragment = new FacebookFragment();
        twitterFragment = new TwitterFragment();

        // TODO the order of this MATTERS if Facebook isn't last
        // Facebook auth breaks and vice versa.
        getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, twitterFragment)
            .add(android.R.id.content, facebookFragment)
            .commit();
    }

    private void restoreFragments() {
        facebookFragment = (FacebookFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        twitterFragment = (TwitterFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
}
```

**Facebook Fragment** (largely based on [SDK documentation example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/login-with-facebook/))

```java
public class FacebookFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private static final String TAG = FacebookFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
            Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.authentication, container, false);

        LoginButton facebookButton
            = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.facebookButton);
        facebookButton.setFragment(this);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(getActivity(), callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && (session.isOpened() || session.isClosed())) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, session.getState(), null);
        }

        uiHelper.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state,
        Exception exception) {
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged in...");
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Logged out...");
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "unknown state " + state);
        }
    }
}
```

**TwitterFragment**

```java
public class TwitterFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.authentication, container, false);

        Button twitterButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.twitterButton);
        twitterButton.setOnClickListener(twitterClickListener);

        return view;
    }

    private OnClickListener twitterClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, TwitterLoginActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
}
```

Why does the order in which the above fragments are added via the `SupportFragmentManger` matter?

Comment: Does both fragment fill whole screen? Can you be more clear on what doesn't work? The buttons doesn't show, they can't be clicked etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void restoreFragments() {
        facebookFragment = (FacebookFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        twitterFragment = (TwitterFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
    }
```

You need to assign each fragment a different id otherwise you will always get the same fragment for a given id. I guess you'd get the first declared/added fragment but that depends in the implementation. (You probably are getting a class cast exception).

To fix this, assign them different ids and add them to different placeholders.

```
.beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.twitter_fragment, twitterFragment)
            .add(R.id.facebook_fragment, facebookFragment)
            .commit();
```

This requires other changes as well but hopefully you can get there.